# SQL Performance tuning - Update query

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my update query below, I have two subqueries. Both are the same except the column it is picking (ColumnA, ColumnB). Single subquery gives more than 100,000 record from which first row will be picked.

But there is performance issue as it is possible to combine two subqueries to single query.

How to combine that.

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET 
LOWEST_RATE = (SELECT TOP 1 ColumnA from Table2 WHERE Table2.Currency = Table1.Currency),
DIFF_RATE = (SELECT TOP 1 ColumnB from Table2 WHERE Table2.Currency = Table1.Currency)
```

Comment: Why are you doing top 1 without an order by? You're not guaranteed the value you want.

Comment: Please explain a bit more about the data volumes. How many rows (in total) for table1? and how many rows (in total) for table2? Are you saying for EACH row in table1 the subquery will scan 100,000 rows in table2.  ["lakh" as a term is not universally understood so I used 100,000]

Comment: What indexes exist on these tables? can we get the DDL including indexes plus some sample data from each table please. (small sample is fine)

Answer (score 0):

Use an updateable CTE, and row_number() to get just a single row for each currency:

```
;with x as (
select Currency, ColumnA, ColumnB,
row_number() over(partition by Currency order by ...) as rn
from Table1
),
y as (
select t1.*, t2.*
from Table1 t1
join x t2 on t1.currency = t2.currency and t2.rn = 1
)
update y
set 
lowest_rate = ColumnA,
diff_rate = ColumnB
```

If you really don't mind which row from Table2, use any column instead of `...`

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can do something like this

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET 
              LOWEST_RATE = (SELECT TOP 1 ColumnA),
              DIFF_RATE = (SELECT TOP 1 ColumnB)
from Table2 INNER JOIN  Table1 
on Table2.Currency = Table1.Currency
```

Answer (score 0):

If am not wrong your `correlated subqueries` can be converted into `INNER JOIN`. Try this.

```
UPDATE A 
SET    LOWEST_RATE = B.columna, 
       DIFF_RATE = C.columnb 
FROM   table1 A 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Max(columna) ColumnA, 
                          currency 
                   FROM   table2 
                   GROUP  BY currency) B 
               ON A.currency = B.currency 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Max(columnb) ColumnB, 
                          currency 
                   FROM   table2 
                   GROUP  BY currency) C 
               ON A.currency = C.currency
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `CROSS APPLY` is an effective way to deal with correlated subqueries which are carried into the update through a CTE.

```
;WITH cte
    AS (
        SELECT
            table1.lowest_rate 
          , table1.diff_rate 
          , ca1.lowest_one
          , ca2.highest_one
        FROM table1
        CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT TOP (1)
                    ColumnA
                FROM table2
                WHERE table1.Currency  = table2.Currency 
                ORDER BY
                    ColumnA  ASC
            ) ca1 (lowest_one)
        CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT TOP (1)
                    ColumnB
                FROM table2
                WHERE table1.Currency  = table2.Currency 
                ORDER BY
                    ColumnB  DESC
            ) ca2 (highest_one)
        )
UPDATE cte
SET
    lowest_rate = lowest_one
  , diff_rate = highest_one
;
```